# Combine useReducer with useState in the same component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I use react hooks `useReducer` that contains my state, let's say I have 3 state fields - `a`,`b` and `c`.
Those fields tie together and mostly change together - so the reducer function is cohesive.
If I have different state field `d` that is not cohesive to the other state - should I use both `useState` (for `d`) and `useReducer` (for `a`,`b` and `c`) at the same component or it's better to use the same reducer function? Moreover - if I have more fields like `d` that changes in similar places - should I use 2 seperate reducers?
What is the best practice for this case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My advice would be use both `useState` and `useReducer`, given `useReducer` is just an abstraction around `useState`.

Just like you wouldn't try to cram all the state of the component into one `useState` hook, you likely should also avoid doing that for `useReducer`.

Answer (score 2):

I tend to try and abstract the `useReducer` to a global context and use `useContext` in conjunction with the reducer to get my application state. However, sometimes it makes sense to use `useContext` and `useState` if the component has an internal state. That being said, I don't think there are any hard and fast rules for hooks at the moment, so I would read up more and make the best choices for your team. That being said, I do agree with what IliasT said about cramming state into one useState. If you go with the `useState` hook use one for each piece of state and don't try and make an object that controls the state.